# How to cause app to launch on startup -- Mac

Tags: macos

There's a way to make an app launch on startup on OS X. In fact, I even **did** it and now have FF launching when I boot my machine. But now I can't remember how you do it.

Would someone remind me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go into System Preferences > Accounts > Login Items, and add or drag the application you want to launch on startup to the list:

[image: Login Items]

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: How about starting a console application on login?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, right click on the application whilst its running in the dock and click "open at login"

Comment: If the app in question does not appear in the Dock, you'll need to use the other method, though.